# How to add Microsoft Word option to the mouse right-click drop-down menu in internet explorer?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, internet-explorer-11

I have a system with Windows 7 Home Basic (64-bit), and Internet Explorer 11. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 5520, with a Core i5 Intel CPU.

When you select some text, like a sentence or word, in Internet Explorer and right-click on your mouse you get the option of sending the selected item to Microsoft OneNote directly. Right? How do I send the same selected text directly to a Notepad, Wordpad or even Microsoft Word directly? How can I add that option also to the drop-down menu which appears after the mouse right-click?

Comment: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/160502-internet-explorer-open-selected-text-into-notepad.html might help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to modify the menu to do what you'd like. But you should be able to accomplish the same result using Copy and Paste. Make sure your target application is open, then highlight the word, phrase, picture, or whatever in IE. You can right-click and select "Copy" or simply use Ctrl-C to put the content onto your clipboard. Then use Alt-Tab or click in the toolbar to switch to the target application, and use Ctrl-V or right-click and "Paste" to paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through an addon/plugin or through editing the registry and writing a simple script.

*warning* Editing the registry wrong can destroy your operating system forcing at worst a full restore. Don't muck about in here and definitely consider making a system restore point before continuing. Also this method will copy the selection to the keyboard but won't actually paste it for you.

- That said, hit your start button and type regedit, and launch the
  app.
- Browse to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\
  If MenuExt should exist for your already because you have the Onenote extension already, but I had to create mine (New Key).
- Then in the MenuExt key, make another new key with the name you want to show in your right click menu, i.e. "Export to Word".
- Create a key in this called "Contexts" and set the (Default) data to 0x10. This tells the option to only show when you've right clicked on highlighted content.
- Create another key called "Flags" and set the (Default) data to 0x1. This will allow the script to access the data you selected.
- Next we're going to need to make a script to point our menu to, I made a file called c:\Users\username\Documents\simple.htm
- In this example I would set the default value of "Export to Word" to "file://C:\Users\username\Documents\simple.htm"
- As far as I've found notepad, wordpad, and word all don't have a method to accept direct text input, only files. So to avoid trying to have this script write temp files, we can try a copy paste method.

simple.htm should look like this

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript">
//find our selected content
var selection = external.menuArguments.document.getSelection();
external.menuArguments.clipboardData.setData("Text", selection.toString());

//create a shell and open wordpad
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
objExec = WshShell.Exec("notepad.exe");

//give it a second to open then paste
WshShell.AppActivate(objExec.ProcessID);

while (objExec.Status != 0)
{
     delayedSendKeys("^V");
}

delayedSendKeys("^V");

//sending keys works better with a delay
function delayedSendKeys(str)
{
    WshShell.SendKeys(str);
    external.menuArguments.console.log("window","sent keys");
}
</SCRIPT>
```

And this is where I get stuck. You can press ctrl+v and paste your selection in the opened window, but from what I've read sendkeys likes a delay, but setTimeout doesn't work and the ie doesn't give us access to the WScript object so we can sleep for 100ms or so.